# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null in select2 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select2 4.0.0 multiselect plugin. 
I want to show existing values bind to it and when I am trying to remove the values then this particular error is coming up.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of null

Here is my initialization for select2

```
$("#multiOptions").select2({
      data:this.permissionArr,
      initSelection: (element, callback) => {
          callback([{id:1, text: 'abc'}])
      }
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue, I'm having the same problem. Little late me asking.

Comment: Are you by chance using DataTables plugin as well?

Comment: Actually there was some issue with the minified version of select2 js file. I resolved this by generating minified version own my own.